# How to write custom RegularExpressionValidator which takes the values from the config file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have to use a Regular expression validator for username property in my model.
I am getting this regular expression from the config file.

```
[RegularExpression(UsernameValidationExpression)] //UsernameValidationExpression = value from the config file
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Here i am getting an error 
"An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"

How can i solve this??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public class ConfigRegularExpressionAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public ConfigRegularExpressionAttribute(string patternConfigKey)
        : base(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[patternConfigKey])
    { }
}
```

and then:

```
[ConfigRegularExpression("UsernameValidationExpression")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

and in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UsernameValidationExpression" value="foo bar" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert this to asp.net core ?